# Edit commits date in Git

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket

I have my own repository. What I want to do is to change the history. I want to change the date of every single commit. Is it possible, if yes - how?
I searched on google, but I didn't really find an answer.

P.s: My repository is in BitBucket and I'm using git core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you have two dates to set:

- `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE`
- `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE`

They both follow the same [date format](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit-tree#_date_formats)

As in this [blog post](http://eddmann.com/posts/changing-the-timestamp-of-a-previous-git-commit/), resetting the dates on one specific SHA1 would be (using [`git filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch)):

```
git filter-branch --env-filter \
"if test \$GIT_COMMIT = 'e6dbcffca68e4b51887ef660e2389052193ba4f4'
then
  export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE='Sat, 14 Dec 2013 12:40:00 +0000'
  export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE='Sat, 14 Dec 2013 12:40:00 +0000'
fi" && rm -fr "$(git rev-parse --git-dir)/refs/original/"
```

Resetting commit fate to author date [would be](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/11624/set-git_committer_date-git_author_date-for-all-the-git-commits):

```
git filter-branch --env-filter 'export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$GIT_AUTHOR_DATE"'
```

You will have to do a `git push --force` after changing the history, which can be problematic if others have cloned your upstream repo.